# send tmux command from inside ssh session

Tags: ssh, tmux

Inside tmux we ssh to a server that doesn't run tmux

```
local>tmux send-key C-p  # works
local>ssh user@remote
user@remote> tmux send-key C-p
tmux: command not found
```

It looks like this more of ssh question.

Answer (score 1):

`tmux` isn't installed on the remote system. Install it.

Answer (score 0):

To communicate with bash, tmux session uses 'unix socket'. That's why installing tmux on remote machine won't help.

What will work is reverse-ssh to your local machine and execute tmux command like:

```
user@remote> ssh user@local 'tmux send-key C-p'
```